# Does it matter if I open other people's stuff?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Sometimes villagers will give me presents for other villagers to deliver, or time capsules to bury, telling me not to open them.

I, so far, have been a good mayor, and resisted the urge to peek at the items.

Other than them being opened, and likely then undeliverable, is there any harm to me taking the presents or opening the time capsules instead of delivering or burying them?

Comment: I betrayed Knox and opened his, he was a bit appauled by my behavior when I came back and talked to him. He did not however pout like they do when they are seething with rage.

Comment: If they complain, hit them with a net.  That should put them in their place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the things they tell you not to look at, it will decrease their relationship with you and they will be more likely to move out, just like bopping them repeatedly with a bug net will make them not want to talk to you.